# save an object into database using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Model Object which named `Student_Info` in the package `com.hibernate`.

In the same package I have a Main class where I created an instance of `Student_Info` :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student_Info student = new Student_Info();
        student.setRollNo(1);
        student.setName("Ichigo");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
                new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(student);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();

    }

}
```

In the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file i have this :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">toor</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping resource="com.hibernate.Student_Info" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But when I run the Main class I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com.hibernate.Student_Info not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:767)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.addResource(AnnotationConfiguration.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.addResource(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2255)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2227)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2207)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2075)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2054)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:177)
    at com.hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

So what's wrong with what I wrote, I think all is set correctly.

## Edit :

This is my project folder structure :

[image]

## Edit 2:

This is the `Student_Info` class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT_INFORMATION")
public class Student_Info {

    @Id
    private int rollNo;
    private String name;

    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }

    public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



}
```

## Edit 3 :

I created a file named `Student_Info.hbm.xml` in the package `com.hibernate` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hibernate.Student_Info" table="STUDENT_INFORMATION" catalog="hibernatedb">
        <id name="rollNo" type="int">
            <column name="rollNo" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` I changed this line :

```
<mapping resource="com.hibernate.Student_Info" />
```

With :

```
<mapping resource="com.hibernate.Student_Info.hbm.xml" />
```

But when I run the Main class I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com.hibernate.Student_Info.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:767)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.addResource(AnnotationConfiguration.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.addResource(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2255)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2227)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2207)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2075)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2054)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:177)
    at com.hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Comment: include import statements of `Student_Info` entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the file `Student_Info.hbm.xml` I had to move it into the folder `src`, and it worked, but I had to change this line :

```
<mapping resource="com.hibernate.Student_Info.hbm.xml" />
```

to :

```
<mapping resource="Student_Info.hbm.xml" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Entity

@Table(name="STUDENT_INFORMATION")

public class Student_Info {

    @Id
    @column(name="your id column name") 
    private int rollNo;

    @column(name="your name column name") 
    private String name;

    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }

    public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



}
```

You did not specify any mapping to your table and If you are not provided any mapping then ORM engine will check for same column names in database as default option and still if if did not find anything It will throw mapping exception. Enable your log and find more information how does Hibernate works...

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: In the `hibernate.cfg.xml` I used this `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`, so it should create a new table named STUDENT_INFORMATION, if there is no table in the database with the properties of the  `Student_Info` class as columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not correct >

```
<mapping resource="com.hibernate.Student_Info" />
```

This tell hibernate where are the hbm files located not the entities, then within the hbm.xml files you be able to add the entities.

```
<class name="Student_Info" table="Student_Info ">
    ...
</class>
```

Indeed

```
com.hibernate.Student_Info not found
```

Means there are not com.hibernate.Student_Info file, consider read [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic.html).

**UPDATE**

In order to fix the next exception you should consider renaming the file as java said.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com.hibernate.Student_Info.hbm.xml not found
```

It means you should use

```
<mapping resource="Student_Info.hbm.xml" />
```

And file name must to be name *Student_Info.hbm.xml* should be at the level of hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Please, see the modification I made to my post

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in **mapping** tag of your hibernate.cfg.xml file.

**Solution For annotation based mappings**

If you using annotation – then in the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the **mapping** tag use ***class*** attribute instead of ***resource***.
It should be

```
<mapping class="com.hibernate.Student_Info"/>
```

**Solution For XML-based mappings**

If you want to use separate hbm file for mapping then in the hibernate.cfg.xml file you should use the resource attribute in the mapping file. But in that case you have to specify the hbm file location just like below (**use / instead of .**)

```
<mapping resource="com/hibernate/Student_Info.hbm.xml"/>
```

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell the hibernate the `Student_Info` is a entity.

Please refer http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-entity

Comment: I did, I used the @Entity annotation to do that, please chack the modification I made to my post.